# C# bool file name

Tags: c#, foreach, boolean

I have this code:

```
bool containsNonAllowedCLEOFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles().Any(file => !allowedCLEOFiles.Contains(file.Name));

if (containsNonAllowedCLEOFiles == true)
{
    //How can I print file names with foreach? For example
    foreach ()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", unAllowedCLEOFiles))); //Print after comma unallowed files, but how to?
    }
}
```

It must print "containsNonAllowedCLEOFiles" files name.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to loop.

You have to use `Where()` for it to filter the files:

```
var NonAllowedCLEOFiles = directory.EnumerateFiles()
                                   .Where(file => !allowedCLEOFiles.Contains(file.Name));
```

and then check if any record found show file names as delimited by comma :

```
if(NonAllowedCLEOFiles.Any())
    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", NonAllowedCLEOFiles.Select(x=>x.Name)));
```